# Trying to deploy a contract on Kovan testnet with Parity and it's waiting forever for a confirmation

Tags: contract-deployment, parity, kovan

It says it's waiting for a contract deployment transaction receipt and it just sits there and waits. It never moves to the completed stage.

It was working fine for me a week ago. What's going on?

Comment: Are you fully synchronized? Which parity version?

Comment: @teeyoovee
Did the answer bellow solve your problem? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a common problem because truffle is using a very low gas price that preventing the deployment.
To solve this try add the following inside truffle.js:

```
gas: 4700000,
gasPrice: 100000000000
```

For More, you can check:
[Solidity + Truffle — Not found at Block 50 error solution !](https://medium.com/@ncloutierweb/solidity-truffle-not-found-at-block-50-error-solution-3d1a7784f00e). (However, I recommend to use more gas price than the suggested in this link specially at test networks where Eth has no real value/price)

If this does not solve your problem, please share more information.